# I am trying to compile mexopencv in Matlab and I keep getting the error "C2065: 'OPTFLOW_LK_GET_MIN_EIGENVALS' : undeclared identifier"

Tags: matlab, opencv, mex

I'm continuously getting this error. Here's what runs before I get stopped, what could be the problem with it? I've run it 3 or 4 times and it come up no matter how often I change the `_SECURE_SCL`it doesn't seem to want to compile. Any ideas?

```
>> mexopencv.make
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 -c 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\MxArray.cpp' -outdir 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\CamShift.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\CamShift'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\Canny.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\Canny'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\EMD.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\EMD'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\FAST.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\FAST'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\FileStorage.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\FileStorage'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\GaussianBlur.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\GaussianBlur'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\HoughCircles.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\HoughCircles'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\HoughLines.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\HoughLines'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\HoughLinesP.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\HoughLinesP'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\HuMoments.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\HuMoments'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\Laplacian.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\Laplacian'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\MSER.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\MSER'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\ORB.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\ORB'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\RQDecomp3x3.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\RQDecomp3x3'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\Rodrigues.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\Rodrigues'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\SIFT.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\SIFT'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\SURF.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\SURF'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\Scharr.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\Scharr'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\Sobel.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\Sobel'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\StarDetector.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\StarDetector'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\adaptiveThreshold.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\adaptiveThreshold'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\approxPolyDP.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\approxPolyDP'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\arcLength.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\arcLength'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\bilateralFilter.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\bilateralFilter'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\blur.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\blur'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\boundingRect.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\boundingRect'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\buildPyramid.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\buildPyramid'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcBackProject.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcBackProject'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcGlobalOrientation.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcGlobalOrientation'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcHist.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcHist'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcMotionGradient.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcMotionGradient'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcOpticalFlowFarneback.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcOpticalFlowFarneback'
mex -largeArrayDims   -I'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\include' -I'C:\opencv\build\include' -L'C:\opencv\build\x64\vc10\lib'  -lopencv_calib3d240 -lopencv_contrib240 -lopencv_core240 -lopencv_features2d240 -lopencv_flann240 -lopencv_gpu240 -lopencv_haartraining_engine -lopencv_highgui240 -lopencv_imgproc240 -lopencv_legacy240 -lopencv_ml240 -lopencv_nonfree240 -lopencv_objdetect240 -lopencv_photo240 -lopencv_stitching240 -lopencv_ts240 -lopencv_video240 -lopencv_videostab240 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcOpticalFlowPyrLK.cpp' 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\lib\MxArray.obj' -output 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\+cv\calcOpticalFlowPyrLK'
calcOpticalFlowPyrLK.cpp 
C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcOpticalFlowPyrLK.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'OPTFLOW_LK_GET_MIN_EIGENVALS' : undeclared identifier 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2012B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Compile of 'C:\Users\Obamaniqua\Documents\MATLAB\mexopencv-master\src\+cv\calcOpticalFlowPyrLK.cpp' failed. 

Error using mex (line 206)
Unable to complete successfully.

Error in mexopencv.make (line 139)
        if ~opts.dryrun, eval(cmd); end
```

Comment: The `master` branch is supposed to work with the latest stable OpenCV version (2.4.5 as of now). I see you are using v2.4.0, please update and try again.. I think this would have been better reported in the project's [issues](https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues) page rather than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: in fact, here is a similar issue: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/issues/54 .